# understanding $http.get and variables set within successCallback

Tags: angularjs, http, controller, get

In the following a part of my current controller I'm working on:

```
var vm = $scope;

/* get all teachers from database */
$http.get('app/php/db.php?action=get&table=data')
    .then(function successCallback(response){
        vm.data       = response.data;
        vm.totalItems = response.data.length;
    }, function errorCallback(response){

    });

console.log(vm.data);
```

Console says data is undefined. How do I manage to be able to read variables set within the successCallback?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are logging it, it will be always `undefined`. Because your call is `asynchronous`. It can take 2ms, 200ms - not sure when you'll get response from server.

You can either log it in successCallback

```
$http.get('app/php/db.php?action=get&table=data')
.then(function successCallback(response){
    vm.data       = response.data;
    vm.totalItems = response.data.length;
    console.log(vm.data);   //here
}, function errorCallback(response){

});
```

**OR** you can do `$watch` within your controller.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.data', function(newData){
   console.log(newData.length);
});
```

Comment: so I am not able to use variables set within the successCallback? For example if I use vm.data.length ... later in the controller it won't work..

using watch i just get an "Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newData.length')"

but vm.data definitely is set. Otherwise ng-repeat would't output the data in the html file.